# creating a class to be able to reduce my code and reuse it

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, class

I am a javascript student so there are things that are still not entirely clear in my head. I want to rearrange my code to make it reusable by passing it certain parameters
At this moment I have built this credit simulator, in a much longer code, it occurred to me to build a class, with that class to be able to feed the data it requires and return the values that I need to be shown on the screen.
The first method "creacionClientes" builds the profile of the credit applicant and saves it in an array, what I need is that the second method which returns a value of the fee that the person must pay, is added in the client's profile requesting the credit. Likewise, I can't find a way for the "calcularCuotas" method to feed on the information that the client variable receives, I'm very stuck and I'm drowning in a glass of water thks!

```
 const datosTabla = document.querySelector("#tftable,tbody"); const tasas = cambiarValorTasas() let planesVisible = false;

class Clientes {
    constructor (){
        this.clients = []
    }
    creacionClientes(nombre, apellido, email, monto, plazo, tasas){
        this.clients.push({
            id: Date.now(),
            nombre: nombre,
            apellido: apellido,
            email: email,
            monto: monto,
            plazo: plazo,
            tasas: tasas,
        });  
    }
    calcularCuotas(monto, tasas, plazos){
        let hoy = new Date()
        let pagoMensual = 0;
        let pagoAmortizacion = 0;
        let pagosIntereses = 0;
        pagoMensual = monto * (Math.pow(1+tasas/100, plazos)*tasas/100)/(Math.pow(1+tasas/100, plazos)-1);
        while (datosTabla.firstChild){
            datosTabla.removeChild(datosTabla.firstChild);
        }
    
        //creacion de fechas sucesivas
        function formatoFecha(fecha) {
    
            fecha = new Date(fecha);
            var dia = fecha.getDate();
            var mesIndex = fecha.getMonth()+1;
            var año = fecha.getFullYear();
        
            return dia + "/" + mesIndex + "/" + año;
        }
    
        for(let i = 1; i <= plazos; i++) {
    
            pagosIntereses = parseFloat(monto*(tasas/100));
            pagoAmortizacion = parseFloat(pagoMensual - pagosIntereses);
            monto = parseFloat(monto-pagoAmortizacion);
            
            var fechaX = hoy.setMonth(hoy.getMonth() + 1);
            //creacion de las filas
            $("#tablaPrestamos").append(`<tr><td>${formatoFecha(fechaX)}
            <td class="valorCuota">${pagoMensual.toFixed(2)}</td>
            <td>${pagoAmortizacion.toFixed(2)}</td>
            <td>${pagosIntereses.toFixed(2)}</td>
            <td>${monto.toFixed(2)}</td>`);
        }
    }     }

function cambiarValorTasas (){
    let plazosOpc = $("#menuPlazos").prop('selectedIndex');
    let opciones = $("#menuPlazos").prop('options');
    if (opciones[plazosOpc].value == 12){
        $('#tasasSeleccion').html(3.95);
    } else if (opciones[plazosOpc].value == 24){
        $('#tasasSeleccion').html(4.19);
    } else if (opciones[plazosOpc].value == 36){
        $('#tasasSeleccion').html(4.36);;
    }
    return $('#tasasSeleccion').val(); } $(document).on('change', cambiarValorTasas);

function mostrarTabla(nombre, visibilidad ){
    let mostrar = document.getElementById(nombre);
    if (visibilidad == false){
        if(mostrar.classList.contains("noMostrar")){
            mostrar.classList.remove("noMostrar")
        }
        mostrar.className += " mostrar"
    } else {
        if(mostrar.classList.contains("mostrar")){
            mostrar.classList.remove("mostrar")
        }
        mostrar.className += " noMostrar"
    } } $('#botonCalc').on('click', (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    mostrarTabla('tasasSeleccion', planesVisible);
    mostrarTabla('tasasLabel', planesVisible);
    mostrarTabla('botonEnviar', planesVisible);
    mostrarTabla('tablaPrestamos', planesVisible);
    planesVisible = !planesVisible;    

})

$('#botonEnviar').on("click", (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    let cliente = new Clientes();
    cliente.creacionClientes($('#nombre').val(), $('#apellido').val(), $('#mail').val(), parseInt($('#aSolicitar').val()), parseInt($('#menuPlazos').val()), parseFloat(tasas))
    console.log(cliente)
    cliente.calcularCuotas(parseInt($('#aSolicitar').val()), tasas, parseInt($('#menuPlazos').val())) })
```

Comment: You should be storing something in `this` if you want to use it from another method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are saving the list of clients **inside** the client

I would try this:

1. Get the list of clients outside every client
2. Create the client on the constructor (instead of creacionClientes)
3. Add it to the clients list before creating the client
4. NOW you can use `this` inside `calcularCuotas` where the client information is stored (e.g. `this.nombre`)

It could be something like that

```
const datosTabla = document.querySelector("#tftable,tbody"); const tasas = cambiarValorTasas() let planesVisible = false;
const clientes = []

class Clientes {
    constructor (nombre, apellido, email, monto, plazo, tasas){
        this = {
            id: Date.now(),
            nombre: nombre,
            apellido: apellido,
            email: email,
            monto: monto,
            plazo: plazo,
            tasas: tasas,
        }   
        clients.push(this);  
    }
    calcularCuotas(monto, tasas, plazos){
        let hoy = new Date()
        let pagoMensual = 0;
        let pagoAmortizacion = 0;
        let pagosIntereses = 0;
        pagoMensual = monto * (Math.pow(1+tasas/100, plazos)*tasas/100)/(Math.pow(1+tasas/100, plazos)-1);
        while (datosTabla.firstChild){
            datosTabla.removeChild(datosTabla.firstChild);
        }
    
        //creacion de fechas sucesivas
        function formatoFecha(fecha) {
    
            fecha = new Date(fecha);
            var dia = fecha.getDate();
            var mesIndex = fecha.getMonth()+1;
            var año = fecha.getFullYear();
        
            return dia + "/" + mesIndex + "/" + año;
        }
    
        for(let i = 1; i <= plazos; i++) {
    
            pagosIntereses = parseFloat(monto*(tasas/100));
            pagoAmortizacion = parseFloat(pagoMensual - pagosIntereses);
            monto = parseFloat(monto-pagoAmortizacion);
            
            var fechaX = hoy.setMonth(hoy.getMonth() + 1);
            //creacion de las filas
            $("#tablaPrestamos").append(`<tr><td>${formatoFecha(fechaX)}
            <td class="valorCuota">${pagoMensual.toFixed(2)}</td>
            <td>${pagoAmortizacion.toFixed(2)}</td>
            <td>${pagosIntereses.toFixed(2)}</td>
            <td>${monto.toFixed(2)}</td>`);
        }
    }     }

function cambiarValorTasas (){
    let plazosOpc = $("#menuPlazos").prop('selectedIndex');
    let opciones = $("#menuPlazos").prop('options');
    if (opciones[plazosOpc].value == 12){
        $('#tasasSeleccion').html(3.95);
    } else if (opciones[plazosOpc].value == 24){
        $('#tasasSeleccion').html(4.19);
    } else if (opciones[plazosOpc].value == 36){
        $('#tasasSeleccion').html(4.36);;
    }
    return $('#tasasSeleccion').val(); } $(document).on('change', cambiarValorTasas);

function mostrarTabla(nombre, visibilidad ){
    let mostrar = document.getElementById(nombre);
    if (visibilidad == false){
        if(mostrar.classList.contains("noMostrar")){
            mostrar.classList.remove("noMostrar")
        }
        mostrar.className += " mostrar"
    } else {
        if(mostrar.classList.contains("mostrar")){
            mostrar.classList.remove("mostrar")
        }
        mostrar.className += " noMostrar"
    } } $('#botonCalc').on('click', (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    mostrarTabla('tasasSeleccion', planesVisible);
    mostrarTabla('tasasLabel', planesVisible);
    mostrarTabla('botonEnviar', planesVisible);
    mostrarTabla('tablaPrestamos', planesVisible);
    planesVisible = !planesVisible;    

})

$('#botonEnviar').on("click", (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    let cliente = new Clientes($('#nombre').val(), $('#apellido').val(), $('#mail').val(), parseInt($('#aSolicitar').val()), parseInt($('#menuPlazos').val()), parseFloat(tasas))
    console.log(cliente)
clientes.push(cliente)
    cliente.calcularCuotas(parseInt($('#aSolicitar').val()), tasas, parseInt($('#menuPlazos').val())) })
```

Comment: Thanks Ramiro, you have helped me a lot, I have corrected some things in the function but it still needs one more twist. Can I write you through the chat?